# Add an IP printer with command line

Tags: terminal, macos, printing

In Printer and Scanner settings, i click on plus sign, select IP and fill the following:

- Address: 10.242.1.xx:80
- Protocol: IPP
- Queue: ipp/2299xxxxx9342/xxxxxxx
- Name: PRINTER-1

I searched on Google but did not give any useful infomation about it
How can i add IP printer in command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lpadmin`

`lpadmin -E -p "PrinterName" -v "PrinterURL" -P "PPD" -o printer-is-shared=false`

- `-E` Enables the printer
- `"PrinterName"` can be anything that describes your printer
- `"PrinterURL"` is the URL or IP address of the printer
- `-P "PPD"` is the PPD file you wish to use  (including the path)
- `-o printer-is-shared=false` turns off printer sharing

The PPD files are usually located in the `/etc/cups/ppd` directory.  If the printer you want to use is not listed, you can download the PPD from the [OpenPrinting](http://www.openprinting.org/printers/) site.

Comment: Thanks. Here is my command that is working `lpadmin -p PRINTER-03 -v ipp://10.242.1.xx:80/ipp/229xxxxxx9342/xxxxxxxx -P /Users/Shared/printer.ppd -o printer-is-shared=false -E`