# How to add printer with lpadmin and have it show up in Printers and Scanners in System Preferences?

Tags: printing, cups

I am using Mojave, and I am able to add a printer using `lpadmin`.  I can then print a test page to that printer using the CUPS web interface.  Additionally, the printer is listed with `lpstat -p`.  However, the printer does not appear in the Printers & Scanners preferences pane, so it is inaccessible from other applications.

Here is the `lpadmin` command I am using:

> lpadmin -p MyPrinter -E -v lptone:/path/to/file

This printer is using a custom CUPS backend (lptone) that is a script that generates a file name using a UUID and then writes the printed content into that file, so the `/path/to/file` portion of the URI is ignored.  I know this part works because I can print a test page to this printer from the CUPS web interface, and I get a file with the test page content generated at the path where the script is supposed to put it.  I have tried doing `lpadmin` as myself and with `sudo`.

If I first add the printer using the Printers & Scanners preferences pane (`address=localhost:631`, `queue=printers/MyPrinter`), then use `lpadmin -p MyPrinter -v lptone:/path/to/file` to adjust the output device (i.e., CUPS backend), the printer remains in the Printers & Scanners preferences pane, and I can print to it from other applications.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?  [Add an IP printer with command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275388/add-an-ip-printer-with-command-line). It looks like there are some options that you might be missing that will identify the printer in Printers and Scanners.

Comment: Thanks - yes, it looks like the problem was that I had not included the -P argument to specify a PPD file.  I didn't see anywhere that that flag was required, but it seems that for the Mac OS (via System Preferences) to recognize the new printer, it must be provided.  I would upvote your answer, but I don't yet have enough reputation.